# How to access https website where "MD2withRSA is disabled" is encountered

Tags: java, exception, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm getting the following exception message: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: algorithm check failed: MD2withRSA is disabled`

I understand that as of java 6 rel 17 support for MD2withRSA was disabled. Unfortunately I'm trying to connect to a site which is using outdated software and I don't have the power to update it. I've no intention of taking back my java version (currently java 6 rel 20) as I don't want the project restricted by this.

This means that I need to get round this issue client side. I'm using some code that I've been provided with but I assume it was written for an older version of java:

```
HttpsURLConnection huc = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(URL + URL_LOGIN).openConnection();
huc.setDoOutput(true);
huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
huc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

OutputStream os = huc.getOutputStream(); // exception is thrown here

os.write(("password=" + webSitePassword + "&submit:login=Login&username=" + webSiteUsername).getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();
huc.connect();
```

Can anyone provide me with a work around which doesn't involve taking back my java version or updating the server?

Comment: it looks like this might be fixed as of release 21 http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/07/javas-recent-ssl-problems.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated my java version to Java 6 Update 30 and I'm no longer getting the exception.

This [blog](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/07/javas-recent-ssl-problems.html) indicates that this issue was fixed in Update 21.

Based on the posts I've been reading this issue affects Java 1.6 Updates 17 through to 20